# Can't access any shared folders even on localhost

Tags: windows, windows-8, vpn

This problem started just before or after I installed Shrewsoft VPN.

Now I'm unable to access any shared folders on the network, I can't even access shared folder on localhost (I can't do \\localhost, but I can edit content directly using the real folder path)

Note:

Results are the same if I'm using Ethernet or Wifi and it's not a permission Issue because I tested giving access to Everyone and it did the same result...

I'm using Windows 8 Professional, I was able to access those shares with the same version of Windows before.

Feel free to ask more information.

Uninstalling Shrewsoft VPN made no difference

Comment: No it did not do anything. The problem is still there...

Comment: All my restore points are after this problem started...

Comment: I'm using Windows 8 Professional

Comment: Does the problem exists on both ends?  In other words can system A not access System B and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, system A can't access any share and can't be accessed. System A can't even access itself. No matter the network I use though. But System A can serve files via ftp and http using appropriated Server (Wamp) and can Ping other System too.

Comment: What do you mean System A cannot access itself, thats not possible, or do you mean it cannot access any folder you have marked to be public.  I suggest you just recreate your Homegroup.

Comment: I mean, I can access C:/Users/XXXX/SharedFolder, but not //localhost/SharedFolder. When I simply type //Localhost it tell me that the path cannot be found like if I misspelled localhost

Comment: I would manually reset your sharing permissions.  I assume you don't have a restoration point from before you installed the VPN software.  A diagram of your network might help better understand the problem.

Comment: My network diagram could be simple as System A contains a Share with access on full control for everyone and System B can't access it. I tried to reset sharing permission, but when i tried to connect it did not ask me for any credential and it tell me "Windows can't connect with XXXXXX". Note that this message is also shown when I try to access //localhost...

Answer (score 0):

Is any VPN configured within Shrewsoft active?  If so, you are tunneled via the VPN and accesses to the underlying network won't work until you are "off" the VPN.

Comment: Shrewsoft was my only VPN, I just uninstall it and the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

Check your network credentials in Control Panel -> User Accounts and Family Safety -> Credential Manager.

You might try to remove the credential for the computer housing the share, so you can re-enter it again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have lost ownership to those files and folders.Try this using Command Prompt :
takeown.exe /r [FolderName]